# Problems with NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsmutablearray

Why do I get this warning in Xcode 4.3.1?

[image: NSMutableArray warning]
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are allocating an NSArray instead of an NSMutableArray ?

Comment: ... it should be `NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"About",nil];`

Comment: @jshin47 even better, `[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:...]`, that way the code isn't  ARC Dependent.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, that's the truth.

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"About", nil];
```

With

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"About", nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should instead be creating your array like this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"About", nil];
```

Notice we send the message to `NSMutableArray`'s class, not `NSArray`'s, so we get a mutable version of the array created.

Answer (score 1):

Just Replace the convenience constructor for NSArray with NSMutableArray..
    [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"About", nil;